# What happened to Buttercup in Kingpin?

Tags: plot-explanation, kingpin

In *Kingpin (1996)*, Buttercup was originally a tall horse

[image]

and then after Roy removed the shoes, somehow the horse shrank

[image]

Apparently, I missed the joke. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to see the [original trailer](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xb0kd5_kingpin-theatrical-trailer_shortfilms), around the 1:49 mark, to understand the joke about Buttercup.

Woody Harrelson is asked to prove that he's Amish by changing the horse's shoes.  As you can see in the above link, he removes the horse's leg up to its knees, thus making it much shorter.  I think this was cut from the movie so it doesn't make much sense to most people.

Comment: The landlady is indeed a woman, but the "tighty-whiteys" and all that stuff going on in the underwear is meant to show how repulsive and decrepit she was, to show just how desperate Harrelson's character was.  If I'm not mistaken, the very end of [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zIDgPVg9HM) is reminiscent of a scene from The Omen.